# HTML Image Overlay Positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a group project for school that is due on the 17th. I'm trying to get an image perfectly centered over another image. I think I essentially got this figured out a couple days ago, but now that I'm working on it on my home computer, the alignment is all screwed up. I need help getting the images centered in the middle of the screen horizontally, and have the top image centered in the middle of the back image. Here's a screenshot, the code, and a link to just the specific code.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

HTML Image Code:

```
<div class="flagpart">
  <article id="flag2">
  <div id="backimg"></div>
  <img src="flag.png" class="flag">
  </article>
</div>
```

CSS Image Code:

```
#backimg {
background-image: url(flag.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
height: 750px;
background-clip: padding-box;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center;
  filter: blur(5px);
z-index: 1;
}

.flag {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -42.5% 0% 0% -25%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}
#flag2 {


}
.flagpart {

text-align: center;

}
```

backimg is the blurred background image, flagpart contains both images, flag2 is another container, and flag is the top image.

Website link:
https://cooking-light-3.spencerleagra.repl.co/recipe2.html

Link to the code:
[Link Here](https://repl.it/@SpencerLeagra/CoralIgnorantDataset)

Also, if anyone has any suggestions overall on how to make the site look better, please, do feel free to say so.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we don't have to analyze all of your website code. Edit your post accordingly and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @pensum Ok, I've changed it so that the link goes to just the specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative and absolute positioning to place the background image and the img on top of each other, than make the container a flexbox to center the img tag:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container > #backimg {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/700/500);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(3px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container > img {
  width: 50%;
}

.container > #backimg,
.container > img{
   position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="backimg"></div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/500" />
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem I've run into now is that now that I'm using a smaller laptop, the image is too big, and when setting it's width and height to smaller values, it isn't centered.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the img tag inside the div with the larger image. Set the larger div to `position: relative` and the img to `position: absolute` so the smaller image uses the larger one has a guide.

html:

```html
<div class="flagpart">
  <article id="flag2">
    <div id="backimg">
      <img src="flag.png" class="flag">
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

css:

```css
#backimg {
  position: relative;
}
#backimg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Because the parent of img is set to `position relative;` and img is `position absolute;`, the smaller image uses its parent as a guide. `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;` set the top left corner of the smaller img at the centre of the larger image, and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` moves half of the width and height of the smaller image top the left and up, to position it at the exact centre. Here's a picture from [victorw999](https://victorw999.github.io/demo_1/builds/development/csspage008.html) that illustrates this:

[image: top: 50%; left: 50%; put the top left corner at the centre. transform: translate(-50%, -50%); shifts the centre of the child to the centre of its parent.]

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it only shows the the flag img, not the backimg.

Comment: @FoxGAMING_NTF For the sake of the clarity of the answer, I did not include the other css codes that you had in #backimg. Put the background-image: url(flag.png); and all the other lines back, and you should see the background image.

Comment: if I add the lines back to #backimg img i only see one blurry image, and if i add it to #backimg and zoom out I see two blurry images.

Comment: Since .flag is a child of #backimg. If you use`filter: blur(5px);` on #backimg, .flag would be blurred too. To work around this, you need to create a transparent div inside #backimg that overlays the #backimg, but has a z-index less than the z-index of .flag, and blur that overlay instead of blurring the entire #backimg. (position absolute, width and height set to 100% and top and left set to 0)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem not so long ago, so here it´s what I did:

- First of all, I used the % for all the measures so the position of
  the elements its over 100% so it doesnt change depending on the
  monitor that you are using.
- Secondly, try to establish the anchor point on the center of the
  element (in this case is the img) by `transform:translate(-50%,50%)`
  so the anchor point is now in the center of the element and its
  easier to position overall. Then you need to establish the distance
  to the top of the parent with `top:50%`.